# PHP Social Algorithm

Tags: php

I have these parameters for my post link.

1) FB Likes (ex: 372)

2) Tweets (ex: 25)

3) Pinterest Pins (ex: 533)

4) Post likes (on my website) (ex: 13)

I want to show the ratings with these data from 0 to 100 (Example: 73.3). But I don't have any idea on rating algorithm. How can I do this?

This is listing posts code.

```
 $args = array(
    'post_type' => 'post',
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'meta_key' => 'wpfp_favorites',
    'numberposts' => 10,
    'orderby'=> 'meta_value_num'
);

$my_query = new WP_Query( $args );
```

I can listing with most liked posts with this code. And I have more custom field. (tweets, fb likes, pins).

I need listing with social counts.

I want explain with this photo:

[image]

Comment: you don't know how to calculate the percentage or you don't know how to do this in PHP ?

Comment: Yes i don't know how can I do it with PHP.

Answer (score 0):

Basic percentage computing

```
$likes = [
    'facebook' => 372,
    'twitter' => 25,
    'pinterest' => 533,
    'local' => 13
];


$lsum = array_sum($likes);

$percs = [];
foreach ($likes as $key => $val) {
    $percs[$key] = $val * 100 / $lsum;
}

// Percs is filled with 'name' => 'percentage'
```

Comment: Thank you. I like this code but how can I integration for all posts listing? Example calcute all social count for current post and show rating score.

Post ID 1: Fb: 372, Tw: 25, Pin: 533, Local: 13 - Score 45.3
Post ID 2: Fb: 2383, Tw: 239, Pin: 22, Local: 293 - Score 77.8

Comment: How the score is computed? Do you have any SQL structure to provide? Do you have any reference for that kind of feature?

Comment: I am using WordPress. I have postmeta for this keys (fb,tw,pin and like).

Facebook postmeta = fb
Twitter = tw
Pinterest = pin
Like = wpfp_favorites

I am using this postmetas.

Comment: I'm making a photo for my idea.